# How do I compare two columns for matching and non matching values and get it in the format that I want?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I find matching and non matching values between two columns and format it in the below manner?

Input:

```
| expected | match | forward | backward | actual |
|----------|-------|---------|----------|--------|
| a        |       |         |          | b      |
| b        |       |         |          | c      |
| c        |       |         |          | r      |
| d        |       |         |          | s      |
| e        |       |         |          |        |
```

Output:

```
| expected | match | forward | backward | actual |
|----------|-------|---------|----------|--------|
| a        | b     | a       | r        | b      |
| b        | c     | d       | s        | c      |
| c        |       | e       |          | r      |
| d        |       |         |          | s      |
| e        |       |         |          |        |
```

`forward` - present in `expected` but not in `actual` (`SQL left outer join`)

`backward` - present in `actual` but not in `expected` (`SQL right outer join`)

`match` - present in both `expected` and `actual` (`SQL inner join`)

`expected` is what I get from an `SQL` query. I have a lot of scenarios when I don't have the `actual` column in the RDBMS, so I would have to use excel to compare. I can compare it usually using `VLOOKUP` but it is time consuming and also it does not give the format I want. I would like a solution which can be done **importantly** with format as above.

I am open to suggestions. I personally do this using python/pandas, but my colleagues aren't used to python, so I would prefer a solution which can be done with a click of a button, or automated via VBA, or a function via Excel, basically anything which I can share with my Excel colleagues which can make their process faster. Currently they do a `VLOOKUP->Filter->Copy->Paste to another sheet`, rinse repeat for all three columns.

One solution provided - https://superuser.com/a/1417235/954024 but it runs very slow and inefficient, my system hung just using that :(

My python solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys


def find_discrepancies(input_file):
    """
    input: df
    output: formatted df
    """
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
    df['match'] = df.loc[df['expected'].isin(df['actual'])].reset_index()[
        'expected']
    df['forward'] = df.loc[df['expected'].isin(
        df['actual']) == False].reset_index()['expected']
    df['backward'] = df.loc[df['actual'].isin(
        df['expected']) == False].reset_index()['actual']
    df = df[['expected', 'match', 'forward', 'backward', 'actual']]
    counts = df.count()
    df.columns = [df.columns[i].capitalize() + ' - ' + str(counts.values[i]) for i in range(5)]
    df.fillna('', inplace=True)

    return df


def main(inputFile, outputFile):
    df = find_discrepancies(inputFile)
    df.to_excel(outputFile, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    inputFile = sys.argv[1]
    outputFile = sys.argv[2]

    main(inputFile, outputFile)
```

Comment: `match` is basically whichever is from `expected` and also present in `actual`. Edited question to clarify that.

Comment: Got it, took me a second to see.

Comment: Could there be duplicate values in column A or E?

Comment: @dwirony No. We make sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution, but this should suffice. I would need to know a little more about your data setup to configure this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateColumns()

    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim testitem As String

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        testitem = Cells(i, 1).Value

        If Application.CountIf(Range("E:E"), testitem) = 0 Then
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = testitem
        ElseIf Application.CountIf(Range("E:E"), testitem) > 0 Then
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = testitem
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        testitem = Cells(i, 5).Value

        If Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), testitem) = 0 Then
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = testitem
        End If
    Next i

Cells(1, 1).Value = "Expected - " & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Match - " & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Forward - " & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 1
Cells(1, 4).Value = "Backward - " & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row - 1
Cells(1, 5).Value = "Actual - " & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Columns("A:E").AutoFit

For i = 1 To 5
    Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(168, 207, 141)
    Cells(1, i).Font.Bold = True
    Cells(1, i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(1, i).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Next i


End Sub
```

[image: img]

Comment: This is amazing!! Thanks. I'll pass this on to the Excel guys. How can I help with the data setup part? Any info you want specifically?

Comment: Well you didn't give many details on the columns/rows - If your columns are really A through E and your data starts in row 2, then this would work fine.

Comment: Yes columns are A through E, and row starts at 2. The reports from SQL are generated exactly like this.

Comment: Hey. This is just an icing on the cake - Is it possible for you to modify your query, in a way that, it returns the no of records available also? Example - Before code, header is `Expected` `Match`... `Actual`. After code, preferred header is `Expected - 5 Match - 2 Forward - 3 Backward - 2 Actual - 4` ?

Comment: Nps I figured it out. Thanks :) I have edited your answer to add that.